# Esp8266 и web-сервер

Tags: html, веб-сервер, arduino, esp8266

Всем привет. По мануалу скопипастил простенький код на поднятие точки доступа и использования в качестве странички отдельнорй html. При обращении плата уходит в ребут. В сериал порте такое:

```
Exception (3):
epc1=0x4000bf64 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x4023d3ed depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffd00 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01a0
3ffffea0:  74736f00 00000001 3ffef674 4020316a  
3ffffeb0:  3ffffe00 3ffef69c 80000000 40205f88  
3ffffec0:  00000001 4020107c 3ffffef0 402080ae  
3ffffed0:  00000001 4020107c 3ffef674 401000e1  
3ffffee0:  3ffef674 3ffee388 3ffef674 40201b5e  
3ffffef0:  3ffe0000 00000000 80000001 80fe84e8  
3fffff00:  3ffef674 3ffee388 3ffee348 402031be  
3fffff10:  0000002f 80000000 81ff0200 0000008f  
3fffff20:  80005054 4aa5c524 40100200 0004aabf  
3fffff30:  00000001 3ffee388 00000001 40100170  
3fffff40:  00000001 00000000 3ffee348 3ffee4e0  
3fffff50:  00000001 3ffee36c 3ffee348 3ffee4e0  
3fffff60:  00000001 3ffee36c 3ffee348 40203453  
3fffff70:  00000000 00000000 00001388 feefeffe  
3fffff80:  00000000 00000000 00000001 40100170  
3fffff90:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee4a0 402034f4  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee4a0 40206828  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe84e8 40100bb1  
<<<stack<<<
⸮⸮⸮
```

Сам код скетча:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#include "index.h"

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
  String s = MAIN_page; 
  server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page
 }

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Configuring access point...");
  WiFi.softAP("ivESP", "123456Qq");

  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Код index.h:

```
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
            <TITLE>My first web page</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
    <CENTER>
            <B>Hello World.... </B>
    </CENTER>   
</BODY>
</HTML>
)=====";
```

При этом если не юзать index.h, а писать в самом скетче вот так, то работает:

```
 server.send(200, "text/html", "<h1>You are connected</h1>");
```

Comment: надо: server.send(200, "text/html", FPSTR(MAIN_page)); Ещё были строки "Configuring access point..." ...  в serial выводе?

Comment: Спасибо! Так работает.